# How to read "Security & Privacy" settings using command line or programatically

Tags: macos, defaults

I would like to read settings from `Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General` tab in my application. In particular I'm interested if user has set up password and if password is required immediately "after sleep or screen saver begins" or after some delay.[image: Security & Privacy General tab]

I was able to find when screensaver kicks in by looking at its defaults.

command line: `$ defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver`

code:

```
CFPreferencesCopyValue(CFSTR("idleTime"),
      CFSTR("com.apple.screensaver"),
      kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
      kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
```

Using the same reasoning I tried to find plist file for "Security & Privacy" but I'm unable to retrieve this settings from any of the plist files in `/Library/Preferences/` or `~/Library/Preferences/`.

I'm interested only in reading values. So my question is, can this be done? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question; are you looking to only find the value of whether a password is required and what the delay might be once the screensaver saver kicks in? Using `defaults read com.apple.screensaver` *without* `-currentHost` should return that information.

Comment: Gosh, I got confused by this thing. Calling this with and without gives completely different result and I need both parts to get all my answers. So, do you want to write an proper answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `-currentHost` then the information returned by `defaults` is restricted to preferences operations to the host the user is currently logged in on (these host preferences can be found in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost`).

> • Operations on the defaults database normally apply to any host the user may log in on, but may be restricted to apply only to a specific
>   host.
>
> • If no host is provided, preferences operations will apply to any host the user may log in on.

```
 -currentHost
  Restricts preferences operations to the host the user is currently logged in on.

 -host hostname
  Restricts preferences operations to hostname.
```

So in order to get the information you've asked about:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.screensaver
```

By omitting the `-currentHost` option it should return:

```
{
    askForPassword = 1;
    askForPasswordDelay = 0;
}
```

If you wanted to use `CFPrefs`:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

#define EX_KEY "askForPasswordDelay"
#define EX_ID "com.apple.screensaver"

extern CFDictionaryRef _CFPreferencesCopyApplicationMap(CFStringRef userName, CFStringRef hostName);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        CFURLRef current_url;
        CFStringRef path;
        CFMutableStringRef plist_path;
        CFPropertyListRef value;

        CFDictionaryRef app_map = _CFPreferencesCopyApplicationMap(
                                   kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
                                   kCFPreferencesAnyHost);
        CFArrayRef urls = CFDictionaryGetValue(app_map, CFSTR(EX_ID));

        current_url = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(urls, 0);
        path = CFURLCopyPath(current_url);

        plist_path = CFStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        CFStringAppend(plist_path, path);
        CFStringAppend(plist_path, CFSTR(EX_ID));

        CFPropertyListRef prefs = CFPreferencesCopyValue(
        CFSTR(EX_KEY),
        CFSTR(EX_ID),
        CFSTR("kCFPreferencesCurrentUser"),
        CFSTR("kCFPreferencesAnyHost"));

        printf("CFPreferencesCopyValue \"%s\" of %s via ApplicationMap at path:\n", EX_KEY, EX_ID);
        CFShow(plist_path);
        CFShow(prefs);

        CFRelease(prefs);
        CFRelease(plist_path);
        CFRelease(path);
        CFRelease(app_map);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
CFPreferencesCopyValue "askForPasswordDelay" of com.apple.screensaver via ApplicationMap at path:
/Users/Username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver
<CFNumber 0x47 [0x7fffbf0a9d80]>{value = +0.0, type = kCFNumberFloat32Type}
```

↳ [OSX Man Pages : defaults](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html)

Comment: I don't see anywhere in (e.g. `defaults read` or the ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/* files where it stores which apps have been granted permissions such as camera access.  I need a LaunchDaemon run script to have this permission, any ideas where to look?